# Check difference between 2 IEnumerables

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

So basically I have the following 2 `IEnumerable lists`

```
List A = {"Personal", "Tech", "Social"}
List B = {"Personal", "Tech", "General"}
```

Now what I want to achieve is, get the difference between `List A` and `List B`, in this case *Social* and *General*.

I also need to determine that *Social* is extra in `List A` and *General* is extra in `List B` to insert and delete accordingly.

I can also have another scenario

```
 List A = {"Personal", "Tech"}
 List B = {"Personal", "Tech", "General"}
```

in this case it would return *General*"

How can I do that with `LINQ`?

Comment: can the list be expected to be sorted? does the index matter e.g. are these differrent `{"foo","bar"}` and `{"bar","foo"}`

Comment: no in that case they are the same.  Position in the list does not matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go

```
var ListA = new List<string> {"Personal", "Tech", "Social"};
var ListB = new List<string> { "Personal", "Tech", "General" };

var insert = ListA.Except(ListB).ToList();
var delete = ListB.Except(ListA).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried your solution but then the lists are exactly the same, its returning 3 results, ie the 3 entries.

Comment: Actually I tried the simple example as stated above here and it worked.  So I have something wrong with my lists, will make them more simple.  Thanks!

Comment: thanks alexb but I have found my problem! :)  Thanks for your help, working perfectly now

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`List<T>.Except()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb908822%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Method.

> Produces the set difference of two sequences.

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> A = new List<string> { "Personal", "Tech", "Social" };
            List<string> B = new List<string> { "Personal", "Tech", "General" };

            var result = A.Except(B);

            //Will print "Social"
            foreach (var i in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/Pz7VYv).

For your second case;

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> A = new List<string> { "Personal", "Tech" };
            List<string> B = new List<string> { "Personal", "Tech", "General"};

            var result = B.Except(A);

            foreach ( var i in result )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/ZN50hf).

Answer (score 1):

`listA.Except(listB)` will give you all of the items in list A that are not in list B.
Than do the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx)

```
var result = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = A.Intersect(B);//"Personal" , "Tech"
var r = B.Except(A);//"General"
```